# Error: vue-composition-api No vue dependency found

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I am having an issue with **vue-composition-api**.
I have included it in my `main.ts` as an include like this:

```
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import Vue from "vue";

import "./_core/plugins/composition-api";
import "./_core/plugins/global";
import "./_core/plugins/cloudinary";
import "./_core/plugins/gtm";

import { provide } from "@vue/composition-api";
import { ApolloClients } from "@vue/apollo-composable";

import vuetify from "./_core/plugins/veutify";
import contentfulClient from "./_core/plugins/vue-apollo-contentful";
import apiClient from "./_core/plugins/vue-apollo-api";

import VAnimateCss from "v-animate-css";

import App from "./app.component.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

import Meta from "vue-meta";

Vue.filter("formatPrice", function (value: string | number) {
  if (typeof value !== "number") {
    return value;
  }
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-GB", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "GBP",
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  });
  return formatter.format(value);
});

import "./scss/_core.scss";

Vue.filter("time", function (value) {
  const date = new Date(value);
  const options = {
    timeZoneName: "short",
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
  };
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  return date.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", <any>options);
});

Vue.use(Meta, {
  keyName: "head",
});

Vue.use(VAnimateCss);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  setup() {
    provide(ApolloClients, {
      default: apiClient,
      apiClient,
      contentfulClient,
    });
  },

  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

`compoistion-api.ts` looks like this:

import Vue from "vue";
import vueCompositionApi from "@vue/composition-api";
Vue.use(vueCompositionApi);

This compiles, but in my application I see this error:

[image]

When digging deeper, I can see that it's complainling about my `graph-query.ts` script, which is imported in my `get-metadata.ts` script and in-turn is imported in `app.component.ts`.

I thought the `main.ts` file is imported first, so it should **use** composition-api before the app is mounted? Am I missing something here?

Let me know if you need more information

Comment: This has already been posted, and you didn't answer comments that addressed the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72882211/vue-composition-api-must-call-vue-usevuecompositionapi-before-using-any-functi

Comment: when you say imported as soon as possible, isn't anything in the main.ts imported first before anything else? If so, this time I have put it at the top of my imports

Comment: There were other modules above it, they could make a difference. But another point was that you dealt with deps and it's likely that they went broken. Package versions aren't shown and they are relevant. The error suggests that vue and composition lib versions are mismatched or else. This still isn't shown in the question

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this: it might be because the composition API plugin is not initialized before using the API.

From [a related github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/544#issuecomment-701314374):

> I had the same issue, it's because you are declaring any reactive elements (ref() / reactive()) before the plugin is installed in your Vue instance.
>
> You can fixing by calling Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) before importing any of your components/store